# Powershell exception using Add-WindowsFeature: could not update the provided feature files in the time allowed

Tags: powershell

I've got a script that adds a set of features on a Windows 2012 R2 server.
Every night the server gets redeployed to test the script automation.

The command I'm running:

```
Add-WindowsFeature PowerShell-ISE, RSAT-AD-PowerShell, RSAT-AD-Tools, RSAT-ADDS-Tools, RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con, RSAT-DNS-Server, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra, Server-Gui-Shell, SNMP-Service, SNMP-WMI-Provider
```

I'm getting different results every night running the same command.
Sometimes everything works as expected, and after the server reboots all the features are properly installed.

In a working scenario the operation took 58 minutes and 24 seconds.

But quite often I get this exception:

```
Exception             : System.Exception: The server could not update the provided feature files in the time allowed.
TargetObject          : 86b9dcf8-80b1-436f-9c01-9b924886b384
CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (86b9dcf8-80b1-436f-9c01-9b924886b384:Guid) [Install-WindowsFeature], 
                    Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAlterationState__CallCycleTimeout,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeature
                    Command
ErrorDetails          : The server could not update the provided feature files in the time allowed.
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
```

In a "non-working" scenario the operation took 41 minutes and 0 seconds

After this exception I perform a reboot and the server comes up with all the features properly installed.
I know I can handle the situation with a try/catch but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to proceed.

Maybe there's some implicit timeout option settings ?

Thank you.